# In MS Access form, how to color background of selected record?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a somewhat complicated looking Access Form with a continuous display (meaning multiple records are shown at once).  I'd like to change the background color of the *selected record only* so the end-user can easily tell which record they are on.

I'm thinking of perhaps a conditional format or maybe something like this:

```
Private Sub Detail_HasFocus()
    Detail.BackColor(me.color)=vbBlue
End Sub
```

and something similar for when that row loses focus. This code snippet obviously won't work, but it's the kind of code I'd like to achieve.

Comment: I don't believe it's doable with conditional formatting, as it cannot be applied to non-data-bearing controls (which the Detail is not). It also can't be done in an event, except that an event can assign a conditional format. Basically, you'd be left adding a control whose conditional format you'd alter in the OnCurrent event, and if you're doing that, you might as well use Dev's solution below and avoid the slowness of conditional formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete solution that correctly treats newly-edited records, as well as handles Access UI quirks (i.e. failed re-paints, inconsistent behavior depending on how a record is selected--via mouse or keyboard or record selector, etc.).  I include verbose comments, because Access requires thorough explanations due to its many inconsistencies and/or bugs.  I have attempted leaner solutions, but inevitably it does not behave well without the tricks to force Access to repaint the form, or complicated ways for determining the current record within the Detail_Paint() event handler.

The code is for an Access form with a textbox bound to an ID Autonumber field.  The form also has a Rectangle control named boxCurrent which is updated to highlight the currently-selected record (it has a wide brightly-colored border).  I find a Rectangle control offers more visual options than setting Detail.BackColor, although such details are openly configurable using the overall pattern.  Developed and tested with Access 2013 and 2016.

```
'* Set this value in From_Current event handler
Private vCurrentAutonumber As Variant

Private Sub Detail_Paint()
  '* Delcare static variables to make often repeated calls more efficient.
  Static iActive As Integer
  Static vThisValue As Variant, vOldValue As Variant

  On Error Resume Next
  iActive = 0 '* Default to False/hidden value

  vThisValue = Me.ID.Value
  If Err.Number = 0 Then
    If Not IsNull(vCurrentAutonumber) Then
      If vThisValue = vCurrentAutonumber Then iActive = 1
    ElseIf Me.NewRecord Then
      '* Form currently set to "New Record", but may or may not be in edit mode.
      '* When in EDIT MODE, AutonumberControl.Value will HAVE A VALUE
      '      AND AutonumberControl.OldValue will be null
      '   When NOT in edit mode, AutonumberControl.Value will be null
      '      AND AutonumberControl.OldValue will also be null
      '*** That is the only way I have found to determine for sure
      '    if the currently-edited-new-record is the available record for
      '    this particular call of Detail_Paint().
      '    Other properties like CurrentRecord, NewRecord, etc. remain
      '    unchanged during repeated calls to Detail_Paint()
      '    and access has no other convenient way to determine the
      '    newly-added autonumber value, so it must be deduced using
      '    this trick.

      If IsNull(vThisValue) Then
        If Not Me.Dirty Then
          'Record selector on *(New Record) row, but not edited yet.
          If Err.Number = 0 Then iActive = 1
        End If
      Else
        vOldValue = Me.ID.OldValue
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
          If IsNull(vOldValue) Then
            '* Newly-edited record with fresh autonumber value is selected.
            iActive = 1

          'Else if vOldValue is not null, it is an existing record.
          '*  Not the current record since it can't be both existing and new.
          End If
        End If
      End If
    End If
  End If

  '* Set these values on EACH CALL, since their values will be retained
  '* on subsequent calls.
  With boxCurrent
    .BackStyle = 0 'iActive
    .BorderStyle = iActive
  End With

End Sub

Private Sub Form_AfterDelConfirm(Status As Integer)
  Me.Repaint
End Sub

Private Sub Form_AfterInsert()
  If IsNull(vCurrentAutonumber) Then
    '* If a new record is saved while staying on that record,
    '*  the Form_Current() handler is not called and so the
    '*  vCurrentAutonumber would not be updated with the newly
    '*  saved value.  But now Me.NewRecord is false, so the
    '*  currently record would not be updated properly unless
    '*  vCurrentAutonumber is explicitly updated here.
    On Error Resume Next
    vCurrentAutonumber = Me.ID.Value

    '* Force repaint (see comment in Form_Current)
    boxCurrent.BackColor = vbBlue
  End If
End Sub

'Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)
  '* Attempted to set some variable or property in this event handler
  '*    --something to indicate to Detail_Paint() which record is the
  '*    new record being edited.  But no matter what I set here, the
  '*    change is present and identical for each call of Detail_Paint(),
  '*    so for the most part this technique was not useful.
  '*    The only alternative is to set one of the data fields, because
  '*    those DO change for each each to Detail_Paint().
  '*    IF THE PRIMARY KEY IS NOT AN AUTONUMBER FIELD (OR IF ANOTHER
  '*    DATA FIELD IS AVAILABLE TO MANIPULATE), ONE COULD FLAG A NEWLY
  '*    EDITED RECORD BY SETTING SUCH A FIELD HERE AND INSPECTING
  '*    it in Detail_Paint().  Personally, I avoid dummy fields just for
  '*    making Access work well and my primary key is Autonumber so it cannot
  '*    bet set to a known new value.
'End Sub

Private Sub Form_Current()

  On Error Resume Next
  vCurrentAutonumber = Me.ID.Value
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then vCurrentAutonumber = Null
  On Error GoTo 0

  '*** FORCE REPAINT of record detail section
  '* If not forced, records are not necessarily repainted for every type of
  '*    UI event.  For instance, changing records using the record selectors
  '*    has different behavior than clicking inside a record, but either way
  '*    the current record has changed and so should be repainted.
  '* But calling Me.Repaint is not sufficient to actually repaint the form.
  '*    Even if the Detail_Paint event is called, the actual visible elements
  '*    are not always repainted (bug?).  It seems that only changing some
  '*    visible feature/control of the form will force an actual repaint.
  boxCurrent.BackColor = vbBlue
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
  vCurrentAutonumber = Null
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

One more way for continuous forms...

1. In the Form's `Form_Current` event set a `TempVar` to equal the value of the current record ID e.g.

```vb
TempVars!CurrentRecordID = Me.ID_xxx.value
'This must one of the conditionally formatted controls per Step 2 below...
Me.ControlName.Refresh
```

*NB. `Me.ControlName.Refresh` is necessary for the conditional formatting to be triggered. You only need to refresh one of the conditionally formatted controls.*

2. Conditional Formatting rule expression is: `[ID_xxx]=[TempVars]![CurrentRecordID]` and set the desired formatting (e.g. `BackColor`)
3. Apply step 2 to any control that you want conditionally formatted when the record is selected.
4. Only the controls on the current record are highlighted

```vb
Private Sub Form_Current()
    On Error GoTo Form_Current_Error
    TempVars!CurrentRecordID = Me.MatterID.Value
    Me.fldDateEngagedEnquiry.Requery

MyExit:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.Screen.MousePointer = 0 'reset to default mouse pointer
    Exit Sub
    
Form_Current_Error:
    MsgBox "Code Line Number: " & Erl & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        "Error " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        " Form_Current of Sub Form_frmMyMatters_SVR"
    GoTo MyExit

End Sub
```

Comment: typo: TempVars!CurrentRecordID = Me.ID_xxx i.e. TempVars with an 's' at the end. Also, you may need to requery just one of the controls in the Form_Current event e.g. Me.fldxxxxxx.Requery

Answer (score 0):

OP here.  Cade pointed out that the original solution's link points to a '97 db which may not be openable anymore.  Also, unfortunately, my original code is long since gone.

However, I recently did something like this using the conditional formatting method which requires no VBA.  This is in Access 2016 on a Continuous Form:

1. In your dataset, add a yes/no field.  Let's call it Rcd_Selected.
2. Make a text box. Also set the Control Source to Rcd_Selected.
3. Change the Fore Color to #FFFFFF (This will be the non-selected color)
4. Change Format to 'True/False'
5. Set Enabled=Yes,Locked=No
6. In the Ribbon, go to Format->Conditional Formatting and make a new rule: Where Field Value =True, set the fore color and back color to your Selected color and click on Enabled.
7. Clean up by stretching the text box over the entire Detail section and moving it to the back.
8. Make a check box field. Sent the Control Source to Rcd_Selected.
9. Stretch the checkbox over the entire Detail section and move it to the front.

Whenever you click on the area, the checkbox will turn on/off triggering the conditional formatting of the textbox in the background to change color.
One limitation of this is that it makes the entire record read-only.  I've never had speed issues and it works when multiple records are selected and un-selected.

Comment: This is definitely the most straightforward option, and the one I was thinking of, too. I was looking for something more simple, but Access only does simple so far.......

Comment: @Paul Thanks, and it only took me 7 years to figure it out :) I agree with you on Access. It's fairly simple to get started and get coding. But the GUI has limited options and doesn't scale up easily to more complex requests like this. These days, I'd write this in Python.

Comment: Yes ... but not Python!  ;o)

Comment: @Paul what would you suggest for a database front end? Ideally.

Comment: Personally, I would go the web route and write a front end in something like Blazor, or the Windows route with C# and whatever the more recent equivalent forms are. I've had so many problems with Access over the years that I can't condone its use for key systems in a company. Presently, I'm dealing with the fall out from 25 years of people writing databases in Access (yes - we still have some Access 97-2003 DBs floating round). The IT directorate for the organisation decided it would be a good idea to upgrade to Office 365 from 2010, a couple of years ago... We have thousands of Access DBs.

Comment: Back 'in the day' Microsoft categorically recommended using 32-bit Office over 64-bit. Now, however, it's the other way round. After a search through one department's file shares, we discovered over 350 different Access databases. That's just one department. We have lots of different departments and employ over 13,000 people. (PS: Apologies for the delay in getting back to you, there).